# SQL | oracle DB | time difference in minutes per location given start and end date

Tags: java, sql

I am not getting proper result , I tried below query , and getting result some strange  decimals

```
  CREATE TABLE "EXAMPLE" 
   ("LOCATION_I" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "START_TS" DATE, 
    "END_TS" DATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "TABLE1_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("LOCATION_I")
    )  ;

Insert into EXAMPLE (LOCATION_I,START_TS,END_TS) values (1,to_date('14-11-17','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('15-11-17','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into EXAMPLE (LOCATION_I,START_TS,END_TS) values (2,to_date('13-11-17','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('14-11-17','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into EXAMPLE (LOCATION_I,START_TS,END_TS) values (3,to_date('12-11-17','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('13-11-17','DD-MM-RR'));

select LOCATION_I, avg(END_TS - START_TS) from EXAMPLE  where END_TS is not null  GROUP BY LOCATION_I;
```

Please suggest solution ..

this is a part of bigger sql .                             .....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: You have error in syntax. Instead of writing to_date('14-11-17','DD-MM-RR'), write to_date('14-11-17','DD-MM-YY').

Comment: RR is generated from sql developer -> SQL tab  for the table